# Send EditText data to pre defined contact number using button click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I have made a program in which i am fetching **device's current location** details and **showing** in **edit text**, but now i want to send device's current location details to **other device using SMS**, and that other device's contact number i would like to define **in my code: XXXXXXX9,**

so please help me to do that how it could be possible for me.....

**Answer:**

I have written code with the help of Nagaraj436 & Appu, like this:

```
String phoneNumber = "XXXX9";
String message = editLocation.getText().toString();
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Message Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
  sendSMS(yourPhoneNumber,editLocation.getText().toString());
}
```

Write and Call the below method on your button click.

```
      private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
       {
           SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
           sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
        }
```

and use the following permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: thanks for help like: my EditText name is : editLocation, so please let me know how my code should look like..to send sms with edit text details

Comment: check my edited answer, in your button onclick method call the sendSMS method by replacing yourPhoneNumber

Comment: I have seen you have written right code, and i have given you what you deserves.....thanks

Comment: please browse this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036327/send-voice-message-to-another-contact-number#comment19391000_14036327

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(contactNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

Where phoneNumber= your destination's number and message is the string which contains your location details.

Based on your comment: Use `editLocation.getText().toString()` to get the location details that you are setting in the edittext.

Comment: thanks for help like: my EditText name is : editLocation, so please let me know how my code should look like..to send sms with edit text details

Comment: thanks buddy i really appreciate your support, but as you know we can choose only one answer you and Nagaraj436 both have given same answers but he has given few mins ago from your answer that's why i have given tick, but for me you both stands on same level....

Comment: Never mind :). As I was busy, I couldn't respond quickly. He solved your problem a bit early, so he deserves.

Comment: You can send through MMS by adding extras to the sms you are sending.

Comment: thanks buddy i am going to ask this question and reply same there and then i will tick to right because i want to give you what you deserves....if possible so show me some code as well.....

Comment: please browse this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036327/send-voice-message-to-another-contact-number

Comment: It seems you pinged me so many times. I am busy. If I had seen your message before, I would have suggested you not to post a question as it increases the questions' flow. Anyways, glad you got an answer.

Comment: Hi buddy and sorry for mistake and i promise you i will not ask any question unnecessarily.....thanks to suggest me, and i am not glad because i did two mistakes first i have asked a question and secondly i did not get what i am looking for, Anyways your guidance will help me in my life definitely :)

Answer (score 1):

> You get the detail of location here:

```
private class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
    @Override 
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {    
     Date today = new Date();  
  Timestamp currentTimeStamp = new Timestamp(today.getTime());  
        if (location != null) {
        Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLatitude() + "");
        Log.d("LOCATION CHANGED", location.getLongitude() + "");
        Strig str = "\n CurrentLocation: "+
            "\n Latitude: "+ location.getLatitude() + 
            "\n Longitude: " + location.getLongitude() + 
            "\n Accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy() + 
            "\n CurrentTimeStamp "+ currentTimeStamp;         
          Toast.makeText(LocationSample.this,str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          tv.append(str);               
        } 
    }
```

Now get the value of latlong and send via sms manager send value

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsNumber, null, youredittex, null, null);
```

Comment: thanks buddy i have done that thanks a lot i like your effort....God Bless You :)

Comment: buddy please browse this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036327/send-voice-message-to-another-contact-number#comment19391000_14036327   sorry forgot to tell you...join us