# send voice message to another contact number

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I have made a program, in which I am **sending some text** to **pre defined contact number**, but now I also **want to send voice message** to that number please let me know how can I do this?

To send text SMS I am using below code:-

```
            String phoneNumber = "XXXX9";
            String message = editLocation.getText().toString();
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "Message Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I think sending text SMS and sending Voice message is totally different scenario....We call to a particular number of our service provider to send a Voice message.

Comment: @samintechvalens can i have an example how code should look like or any tutorial link...

Comment: You just need to call intent for making a call to your voice mail number of your respective service provider, and thats what you can do programetically, rest of the things are totally in your network provider control.

Comment: @samintechvalens buddy thanks i know how to call intent but my problem is i don't know how to work with voice messages using intent, if possible so please me some code for more clarification

Comment: my dear, get my point what I want you to understand, "To send a voice message we need to Call(phone) to a particular number, number depends on your service provider." As you said you know how to call intent for making a call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer this [link](http://jtribe.blogspot.in/2008/12/sending-mms-with-android.html). In this link there is an explaination on how to send images via MMS. you can just replace the image file with the Audio File. you can find the code to send voice message in the Comments of the above link.

Comment: thanks a lot.. buddy i also want to know what are the permissions i need to add in my Manifest..

Comment: send sms permission which I have given you in earlier answer

Comment: i am using above tutorial link, will it play audio like i want to send voice message or just send that mp3 audio file to other device...please clear because in my case i want to send voice message like: Ringtone.....

Comment: @Nagaraja436 buddy please tell me it just send the audio file or play the audio on button click:-  Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          sendIntent.putExtra("address", "XXXX9"); 
          sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Help Me");     
          sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url)); // url would point to mp3 file
          sendIntent.setType("audio/mp3"); 
          startActivity(sendIntent);

Comment: @CarryHog it just sends audio file but not play the audio.

Comment: hi buddy how to send voice messages to another contact number that should play.....

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text");     
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url)); // url would point to mp3 file
sendIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. buddy also want to know any permission which i need to add in my Manifest file....